# How to know the category of credit card according to the number

Tags: credit-card

I would like to know if there is any way to know the category of credit card through its number or part of it. Not the brand (Visa/Mastercard/AmericanExpress) but the category: Classic, Gold, Platinum, Black/Signature, etc.
Does anyone know of a reliable way to find this?

Comment: Is the only information you have about the card the number, expiration date, and security code?

Comment: Yes, and with the card number (BIN) I can get the brand, if necessary.